# Identifying a ruled surface from mechanics

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

This is a problem carried over from theoretical mechanics. The moving axode of a rigid body traversing a given curve $\gamma$ is essentially a "conoid" given as :
$${x}(s,t) = \dfrac{\kappa}{\kappa^2 +\tau^2} N_0(s) + t (\tau T_0 +\kappa B_0)$$
where $\kappa, \tau, T,N,B$ are all quantities associated with the Frenet frame of the curve $\gamma$.

If the $x,y,z$ are coordinates along $T_0,N_0,B_0$ respectively,I get 
\begin{align}
x &=  t\tau \\
y &=  \dfrac{\kappa}{\kappa^2 +\tau^2} \\
z & = t\kappa,
\end{align}

where $T_0, N_0, B_0$ are the directions of the vectors at an initial point when the moving frame and the coordinate frame coincide. 
I am interested in the particular case when $y = \dfrac{\kappa}{\kappa^2 +\tau^2}$ is a constant. I think the surface would then be a cone. Am I right? or is my intuition wrong?

This is a link to the paper I took this problem from:
[Selig](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00022-016-0331-5.pdf)

Comment: You can't do that. $T,N,B$ are constantly varying, so you can't choose a *fixed* coordinate system aligned to them! :P

Comment: @TedShifrin, Oh, but I just came across a paper where the same has been done. I will post a link in the question

Comment: @TedShifrin My bad, the direction of the axes is fixed by taking the initial directions of the $T,N,B$ axes. I will edit the question again. Thanks a lot for that. It looks pretty bad in hindsight.

Comment: But, once you've edited, this is garbage. Those aren't the equations at all.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Could you take a look at the paper? It's on page 9. I am sorry for the bad math.

Comment: No, it seems they're talking about the equations relative to the moving reference frame, which is OK. Just don't think of it as something in a fixed coordinate system.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Thank you. Is my guess about the surface being a cone in the special case correct?